# UserControls Classname-Namespaces issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls

I want to change Control(@Control) directive in a way to make it redistributable and want to use ClassName attribute

so I changed this

**From :**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="ProductShower.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyCompany.Web.Controls.ProductShower" %>
```

**To :**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="MyCompany.Web.Controls.ProductShower" %>
```

with this change I get lots of errors saying all my events one by one don't have definitions !

#### Update:

When I add the ClassName attribute in combination with two others , It causes another error :

```
Error   4   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MyCompany.Web.Controls.ProductShower'; another partial declaration of this type exists c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\productspanelx2\1f971ff6\ea7644da\App_Web_giywejva.0.cs   138
```

in addition to that , the class definition's first line is :

```
public **partial** class ProductShower : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Did you change the name of the Code behind file and make sure that when compiled that it changes the name of the designer file to match your To:

Comment: I edited it recently , pls look at it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new way, you're missing the **CodeFile** and **Inherits** attributes.

The **Inherits** attribute tells the control which class has the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

**Inherits** and **ClassName** must point to different classes in the namespace.

If your control inherits from MyCompany.Web.Controls.ProductShower, make your classname be something like that: MyCompany.Web.Controls.ProductShowerControl (that's how we name controls).